# Embedding matplotlib plots in Sphinx: how to show documentation

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, python-sphinx

I have some `ipynb` documentation with `matplotlib` plots shown inline by `%matplotlib inline` directive.

And I have my Sphinx documentation when I try to show my notebook with inline-drawn plots. I try to use

```
ipython nbconvert shalom.ipynb --to rst
```

But alas, it does give me an RST without of any inline graphics. With only code listings.

**Cannot you tell me, how to generate Sphinx documentation with already-rendered plots.**

I know that it's possible.

Comment: If you know it's possible why are you asking us? :)

Comment: If I knew how to do it just now, I would already done it. But alas, I'm too dumb to guess how to cope with it.

Comment: Haha it's okay :) Fortunately some of us are good at Google and some of us intimately familiar with Sphinx :) either/or/and :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [Sphinx extensions for embedded plots, math and more](http://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/extensions.html)

> Sphinx is written in python, and supports the ability to write custom
>   extensions. We’ve written a few for the matplotlib documentation, some
>   of which are part of matplotlib itself in the matplotlib.sphinxext
>   module, some of which are included only in the sphinx doc directory,
>   and there are other extensions written by other groups, eg numpy and
>   ipython. We’re collecting these in this tutorial and showing you how
>   to install and use them for your own project. First let’s grab the
>   python extension files from the sphinxext directory from git (see
>   Fetching the data), and install them in our sampledoc project
>   sphinxext directory:

You will need to modify your `conf.py` to include:

```
extensions = [
          'matplotlib.sphinxext.mathmpl',
          'matplotlib.sphinxext.only_directives',
          'matplotlib.sphinxext.plot_directive',
          'matplotlib.sphinxext.ipython_directive',
          'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
          'sphinx.ext.doctest',
          'ipython_console_highlighting',
          'inheritance_diagram',
          'numpydoc']
```

Comment: And what if I already have an ipynb and just want to tell Sphinx to make it one single page?

Comment: Good question; let's see if we can find an answer ;)

Comment: ``sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees . _build/html your_filename.rst`` will something like this do the trick?